# Error Message while programming using avrdude and Codeblock

Tags: codeblocks, avr-gcc

I was setting up codeblock for AVR. I am able to compile and build. But while buring using avrdude, I see lot of stderr messages. Can anyone tell what could be the reason? The program however gets written correctly to the controller.

My post build configuration in code block is
avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .text -j .data $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE) $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE).hex

Below is the Error Details:

```
    Launching tool 'Serial Programmer': C:\Atmega\programmers\avrdude.exe -C"C:\Atmega\programmers\avrdude.conf" -pm328p -carduino -PCOM2 -b115200 -Uflash:w:EmbeddedProject2.elf.hex (in C:\Atmega\Projects\Codeblock Projects\EmbeddedProject2\bin\Debug)
stderr> 
stderr> avrdude.exe: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
stderr> 
stderr> Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s
stderr> 
stderr> avrdude.exe: Device signature = 0x1e950f
stderr> avrdude.exe: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
stderr>              To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
stderr> avrdude.exe: erasing chip
stderr> avrdude.exe: reading input file "EmbeddedProject2.elf.hex"
stderr> avrdude.exe: input file EmbeddedProject2.elf.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
stderr> avrdude.exe: writing flash (11674 bytes):
stderr> 
stderr> Writing | 
stderr> ##
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> ###
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> ###
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> ###
stderr> ###
stderr> ###
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> ## | 100% 1.90s
stderr> 
stderr> avrdude.exe: 11674 bytes of flash written
stderr> avrdude.exe: verifying flash memory against EmbeddedProject2.elf.hex:
stderr> avrdude.exe: load data flash data from input file EmbeddedProject2.elf.hex:
stderr> avrdude.exe: input file EmbeddedProject2.elf.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
stderr> avrdude.exe: input file EmbeddedProject2.elf.hex contains 11674 bytes
stderr> avrdude.exe: reading on-chip flash data:
stderr> 
stderr> Reading | ##
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> ####
stderr> ###
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> ##
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> #
stderr> ### | 100% 1.51s
stderr> 
stderr> avrdude.exe: verifying ...
stderr> avrdude.exe: 11674 bytes of flash verified
stderr> 
stderr> avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.
stderr> 
Tool execution terminated with status 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing output in stderr because avrdude outputs to stderr. If you want to suppress non-error output then pass `-qq` to avrdude.